# Proving a lemma of integrability

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

Suppose $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$. Prove that if there exist sequences $P_n$ and $Q_n$ of partitions of $[a,b]$ such that $\lim U(f,P_n) = \lim L(f,Q_n) = L$, then $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b f(x) \,dx = L$.

The first thing that came to my mind was the Cauchy criterion for integrability. Since we have $\lim U(f,P_n) = \lim L(f,Q_n) = L$,  we can assume that $U(f,P_n) - L  < \varepsilon/2$ and $L(f,Q_n) - L  < \varepsilon/2$. By using the trangle inequalities, we can get $U(f,P_n) - L(f,Q_n)  < \varepsilon$. However, this is not $U(f,P_n) - L(f,P_n)  < \varepsilon$.  I do not know how to move forward.

Another method I can think of is to prove that $\lim U(f,P_n) = \lim L(f,Q_n) = L = U(f) = L(f)$ , which is the same to prove that $\lim U(f,P_n) = \lim L(f,Q_n)= \sup\{L(f,Q_n)\} = \inf\{U(f,P_n)\}$. I do not know how to move forward with this method, either.

My instinct told me that the best way to solve this problem is to use the Cauchy Criterion for integrability, but I felt really lost since we have two partitions here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For every $n\in\Bbb{N}$,
\begin{align}
L(f,P_n)\leq \sup\{L(f,P)\}\leq \inf\{U(f,Q)\}\leq U(f,Q_n)
\end{align}
Let $n\to \infty$ and use the fact that inequalities are preserved when taking limits to deduce
\begin{align}
L\leq \sup\{L(f,P)\} \leq \inf\{U(f,Q)\}\leq L.
\end{align}
This completes the proof (why? think of the definition of the integrability and the integral).

---

Using the other approach, given $\epsilon>0$, as you have mentioned there is an $n\in\Bbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align}
U(f,Q_n)-L(f,P_n)<\epsilon.
\end{align}
So, all we have to do is refine the partition by setting $P=P_n\cup Q_n$ (because a refined partition makes upper sums smaller and makes lower sums bigger (I mean with weak inequalities not necessarily strict ones)). Then,
\begin{align}
U(f,P)-L(f,P)\leq U(f,Q_n)-L(f,P_n)<\epsilon.
\end{align}
This proves integrability (recall that all we have to do is find *some* partition which works for the $\epsilon$ bound).

Comment: Thank you for a nice proof. I would be very grateful if you could prove the converse statement too. That is, if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and $L$ is the integral, then there exists sequences $P_n$ and $Q_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} U(f,P_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} L(f,Q_n) = L$.

Comment: @schn I could prove it, but this is a rather simple exercise which you should attempt. It follows pretty directly from the definitions. In fact you can even take $P_n=Q_n$ (by taking their common refinement). Particularly the fact that supremums can be approximated by a sequence is helpful.

Comment: Hmm, is the fact that supremums can be approximated by a sequence trivial? My attempt so far is the following: if $f$ is integrable and $L$ is the integral, then we have $L-\epsilon<\mathrm{sup}\{L(f,P)\}\leq\mathrm{inf}\{U(f,P)\}<L+\epsilon$. Now, then I would like to say something as "there exists a $P_n$ such that $L-\epsilon<L(f,P_n)\leq\mathrm{sup}\{L(f,P)\}\leq\mathrm{inf}\{U(f,P)\}\leq U(f,P_n)<L+\epsilon$" and then we would be done. But I don't know how to justify that there exists such a $P_n$.

Comment: @schn well such a partition does exist, and you should think about why based on definitions of supremum and infimum (also you should take $\epsilon=1/n$ or just some sequence converging to 0). This has nothing to do with integration theory.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to go...

Let $R_n$ be the common refinement of $P_n$ and $Q_n$.  That is if $a=p_1 < p_2 < \cdots < p_{n-1} < p_n = b$ and $a=q_1 < q_2 < \cdots < q_{n-1} < q_n = b$ are the partitions $P_n$ and $Q_n$, respectively, set $R_n = \{p_i : 1 \leq i \leq n\} \cup \{q_i : 1 \leq i \leq n\}$.  (Notice that this avoids duplicates, so all intervals in $R_n$ have positive width.)  Then
$$  L(f,Q_n) \leq L(f,R_n) \leq U(f,R_n) \leq U(f,P_n)  \text{,}  $$
and you can finish by the squeeze theorem (since you know where the sequences on the left and right ends are going).